# How can I add support for SVG media files in Kentico when using Azure blob storage?

Tags: asp.net, azure, svg, kentico

We have a Kentico instance which stores media files in Azure blob storage. When uploading images of type SVG it's storing them with the default content type "application/octet-stream". This means they're not displaying correctly in the browser. The fix would be to use the correct content type "image/svg+xml". Does anyone know if it's possible to force Kentico to use this content type for SVG files?

I realise this can be done after upload using Powershell but that's a technical step not appropriate to roll out to content editors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add your own mime types to **~/App_Data/mimetypes.txt file**. I just checked the source code and "**application/octet-stream"** is used as a default value when the mime type for extension is not found here.

The other thing to do might be to set **Disposition** of the response. By default the SVG images will be treated as attachments in the HTTP headers which means most browsers will try to **download** it instead of displaying. It seems that you might be able to fix this by using your own list with inline attachments. Try adding this to your web.config:

```
<add key="CMSGetFileDispositionInlineExtensions" value="pdf;swf;swg" />
```

It would we awesome if you could let me know if that helped!

Comment: Amazing, it was your first advice that solved this. Added svg to mimetypes.txt, restart app, and subsequent uploads save in blob storage with correct content type. I'm extremely grateful, ta very much :)

Comment: Awesome, I'm happy it helped :-)